# How to check if an answer is an integer or not in Xcode console

Tags: xcode

What I am trying to do is find the factors of numbers. In order to do so, I have created two variables, in order to check if it is a factor of the number I divide the number to check if it equals an integer. What I am asking that you tell me is how to check if a division of two numbers is an integer or not.

Here is my code:

```
int x, y;
        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Factors of...");

        scanf("%i", &x);

        NSLog(@"Here are the factors: %i", x/y);

        for (y=0; y <= x; y++) {
            if (x % y = //does not or equals integer){

            }
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my approach:

```
int x, y;
        //insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Welcome to the factors program. Type in your integer. Up to a 15 digit number!");

        scanf("%i", &x);

        for (y = 1; y <= x; y ++) {

            if (x % y == 0){

            NSLog(@"%i", y); //factors program

            }
            else{

            }
        }


    }
    return 0;
}
```